# What is the security flaw in this authentification process over unsecure HTTP?

Tags: security, authentication, md5, sha256

First question here :)

I've been reading many questions about how to secure login on sites without https. They are all very interesting and most answers boil down to "Use SSL if you care about security!". I agree with this, yet I also wonder, what is the flaw in this particular procedure (**one user(=me), no sessions: the password is always sent with the complete content of the <html> tag, which replaces the current contents of that file.**):

- Server sends two variables to page: random token A and B=derivedfrom(A).
- client sends back md5(password+timestamp+B) and A.
- Server derives B from A to perform the same md5hash as client and matches hashes of server and client.
- Server allows no more than 1 request per second per IP address.

Assuming the attacker knows all valid pairs of A and B, is there any way for him/her to authenticate succesfully apart from replay attacks (during a 100ms timeframe that the hash is valid) and pure luck that he guesses the right hash for this particular timeframe?

Of course, the attacker could still try all possible passwords, but that doesn't change by using https.

I'm not suggesting this is a useful strategy for sites that cannot use https, just wondering if there is a theoretical flaw that I didn't think of.

How would you force your way in if the site has no traffic at the moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several flaws here:

- You should not use md5. Please use some other hashing algorithm (e.g. sha256)
- In order to do what you are saying, the server needs to store the passwords in plaintext. This is a very bad practise, as if you get hacked, all the passwords will be compromised. Instead, you should store a salted hash of the password. More info here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet
- This method is infeasible, as the timestamp cannot be possibly known by the server, except if the clock of the client and the server are synchronised to the millisecond (don't assume that they will be). Even if the clocks are completely synced, this will still not work. The time from when the client takes the timestamp until the packet reaches the server is variable, and the server would need to know exactly that time. Without the correct timestamp, the server won't be able to calculate the hash. Removing the timestamp will lead to replay attacks.
- An attacker performing a man-in-the-middle attack can alter the HTML (or whatever) code on the fly and remove the hashing function (assuming it's performed in JavaScript). The browser will then transmit the password in clear. Of course the authentication will fail, but the attacker will have the password.
- Probably other flaws also exist, but these are enough for the method to be inefficient I believe.

Bottom line: **Do not** use HTTP for user authentication. I have not heard of any cases of secure authentication over HTTP. If SSL is very expensive, you can use it only for the login page. It is still a very bad practise, as an attacker can perform session hijacking by stealing session cookies (and other man-in-the-middle attacks), but at least the password will not be revealed this way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just to clarify a few points: there is only one password stored on the server in plaintext (mine). If the server is hijacked I have a more serious problem than giving away my password. What you say is however very important to protect other people's passwords, just doesn't apply to this case of only one user. Regarding the timestamp, it's rounded to 100ms (or to 10ms if that proves reliable enough.) Just how exactly do you suppose the HTML would be changed in my browser?

Comment: However, supposing that the clocks of the client and the server are perfectly synced, in 100ms the client has to calculate the hash, and send it to the server over the network. If your internet connection is not fast enough, this will always fail. Changing the HTML when you are not using SSL is super easy when performing a MITM attack. Check tools like ettercap. Here is a simple script for example: https://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/ettercapfilter Instead of an image you can change any HTML content (scripts etc.).

Comment: If you are interested in more details regarding the MITM attack please check here: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/72652/javascript-injection-using-man-in-the-middle-attack

Comment: thank you for the link to the MITM answer. I've definitely learned something from that! So basically I can't be sure that the page I am typing in here corresponds 1 to 1 to the content that stackoverflow.com wanted to send me :) Can you think of any other flaws though?

Comment: Exactly! Someone can also steal session cookies and hijack your account by performing MITM on a non-SSL connection. They will not know your password, but they will be able to use your account normally. This is yet another issue (but I have already mentioned it above). Anyway, I'll try to think of more, but I think that these are more than enough reasons to not use plain HTTP. Except if you want to protect yourself from very basic script kiddies.

Comment: So why is stackoverflow.com not forcing a https connection then?

Comment: There is an https version of the website. I don't know exactly why they're not, but I am guessing it has to do with the cost (you need much better servers if you have to deal with huge number of users), and that in some countries https connections are not allowed. Also, its login page is protected by SSL. Through a MITM attack though, you can easily be redirected to a malicious, fake login page, controlled by the attacker. Check this article: https://www.troyhunt.com/is-stack-overflow-secure-kind-of/

Comment: And yes, using MITM you can also redirect someone to a malicious website that hijacks the username/password of the user. There are even tools where you give a URL as an input and they clone the corresponding website automatically, and host it on your machine. You can perform various attacks using this method, from from stealing passwords, to taking full control of the target computer that accesses that website.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is a minor technical detail in a larger *procedure*, which you do not go into detail at all. I'm *assuming* that the larger purpose of that procedure is to *log in*? Then what happens after this token is exchanged? Does the user receive some sort of permanent token like a cookie? Then this is susceptible to:

- man in the middle attacks reading all communication
- local network packet sniffing, famously publicised by the [Firesheep attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firesheep)

Even *if* (that's a **large if**) this particular token scheme were flawless, the entire communication chain is observable by third parties and all private data (including identifying cookies) can be read in the clear by unauthorised users in a privileged network position (→ [session hijacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking)).

Comment: The procedure is this in my case: user edits a html page (with <html contenteditable>) and then sends the html tag through ajax to a php script, which verifies that the password matches and if so, replaces the file that the request came from. There is no session as I mentioned. The communication is not sensitive, as it is just the content of a public page that is getting updated. Also there are no cookies involved, so I don't see how the Firesheep attack applies.

Comment: OK, Firesheep doesn't apply then. But man-in-the-middling still very much applies; an attacker in a privileged network position can rewrite your request and alter any content you're trying to upload (most likely adding malicious scripts and such to it).